# openldap setup on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, openldap, kops

I want to set up OpenLDAP in a Kubernetes cluster running on AWS.
I’ve applied YAML files “https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap/tree/stable/example/kubernetes/simple” except for service type I choose load balancer.

I’ve added below two ldif files:

## base.ldif

```
dn: ou=People,dc=example,dc=com   
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: People
dn: ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Group
```

## test.ldif

```
dn: uid=test,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
cn: test
uid: test
uidNumber: 9999
gidNumber: 100
homeDirectory: /home/test
loginShell: /bin/bash
gecos: test admin user
userPassword: password
shadowLastChange: 17058
shadowMin: 0
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7
```

I’ve setup LDAP client on centos 7 system but no result is showing if I execute “getent passwd test”

Please help me with this?

Comment: How did you set up your LDAP client? is it pointing to the LDAP server?

Comment: Using the below command: 
authconfig --enableldap --enableldapauth --ldapserver=<aws_elb_ip> --ldapbasedn='dc=example,dc=com' --enablemkhomedir --update
FYI: from the client the ip/port is reachable and ldapseach is working.

Comment: Issue resolved: ldap client can't translate aws long elb name. Created a route53 entry for elb.